# Overloading concept with an example

Tags: c#

How do I use Overloading method for this example. When I send an increment, it should give me the new value. If I don't give an increment, it should add a default value. This is in c# asp.net.

For example:

```
 GetY(y,3)  // add 3 to y 

 or GetY(y) //add default value of 15
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an optional parameter to specify a default value, and then overloading isn't necessary.

```
public int GetY(int y, int add = 15) {
    return y + add;
}
```

This is the same as the following overloaded version:

```
public int GetY(int y) {
    return GetY(y, 15);
}

public int GetY(int y, int add) {
    return y + add;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public int GetY(int y, int increment)
{
    return y + increment;
}

public int GetY(int y)
{
    return GetY(y, 15);
}
```

Comment: Your method arguments need data types.